# Regular Expression with combination of numbers,alphabets

Tags: java, pdf

I'm trying to retreive the information from PDF file using java

> PRODUCT(SINGLESPACE)11200216(TABSPACE)TOTAL(SINGLE 
>   SPACE)32(>2TABSSPACE)47.58 
>   PRODUCT(SINGLESPACE)112002(TABSPACE)TOTAL(SINGLE 
>   SPACE)34542(>2TABSSPACE)122347.58

I tried regular Expression

```
 while((!(headitems1[index].matches("product\\s\\d{8,}[\\W]{1,}total"))))//||(!(headitems1[index].contains("TOTAL"))))
 {
     count++;
     index++;
 }
```

But it is not working , Please suggest me any solutions.

Comment: Try doubling the backslashes: \\s instead of \s etc. If it still doesn't work, post a full Java program (not just a code snippet) and its input for which which fails.

Comment: `Information from PDF file`?  Are you trying to parse a PDF using regexps?

Comment: for(int index=0;index<headitems1.length;index=index+1)
         {
          
          a= headitems1[index]; 
          System.out.println("Element 'a'   :"+a);
try{
  while((!(headitems1[index].matches("product\\s\\d{8,}[\\W]{1,}total"))))//||(!(headitems1[index].contains("TOTAL"))))
  {
    count++;
    index++;
   }
 
         //while((!(headitems1[index].contains("PRODUCT")))||(!(headitems1[index].contains("TOTAL"))))
          
          copyfourelements(count,a);
}catch(Exception e){}

Comment: ya am trying to parse using PDDocument and can u  suggest me regular expression

Comment: This is my code but not workingtry{
  while((!(headitems1[index].matches("product\\s\\d{8,}[\\W]{1,}total"))))
  {
    count++;
    index++;
   }

Comment: Try changing `product` to `PRODUCT` and `total` to `TOTAL` in your regexp, to match the uppercase in your input. An alternative is prepending `(?i)` to the regexp, which enables case-insensitive matching.

Comment: To get help more easily here, please post a minimal, self-contained `.java` file (including the `main` function) containing an input string and a regexp match call. This way we can make sure that the bug is related to regexp matching.